# UILabel.text not changing before last For Loop execution

Tags: swift, for-loop, uilabel, sleep

I'd like to change a UILabel.text every second for a String inside an Array.

To do so, I wrote the following code and placed it inside the viewDidAppear.

```
let countdown = ["3", "2", "1", "GO !"]

for i in 0..<countdown.count {
    self.countdownStatus.text = countdown[i]
    sleep(1)
}
```

**What's happening**

UILabel.text is not changing before 4 seconds then get the last String of the Array.

> sleep(1)
>
> sleep(1)
>
> sleep(1)
>
> sleep(1)
>
> GO !

**What's expected**

> 3
>
> sleep(1)
>
> 2
>
> sleep(1)
>
> 1
>
> sleep(1)
>
> GO !
>
> sleep(1)

Comment: Don't do a `sleep()` in main thread, that's blocking the UI. And you can update the UI only in main thread, so if you did it in background, you need a Dispatch for setting the label text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid UI blocking, dispatch whole routine to a global que, and dispatch the UI part to main queue.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let countdown = ["3", "2", "1", "GO !"]

    for i in 0..<countdown.count {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.countdownStatus.text = countdown[i]
        }
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not try with a timer instead?

This is untested.

```
let myTimer : Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.performCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

let countdown = ["3", "2", "1", "GO !"]
var i = 0
func performCountdown() {
    while i < 4{
        print(countdown[i])
        i = i+1
    }
```

You can also use a background thread, this is **tested and working**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
let countdown = ["3", "2", "1", "GO !"]
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    for i in 0..<countdown.count {
        print(countdown[i])
        sleep(1)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Alec! Thank you for your answers, unfortunately they didn't worked. Untested one: same result as in my question, the print do work, but the UILabel is only getting the last value. Tested solution: The background thread got me into an error "UILabel.setText(_:) must be used from main thread only".

Comment: Yes. UI operations should only be run on the main thread. He is only doing print in the main thread. The accepted answer does it the right way.